# Passing token to another request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In first request I'm asking external server to provide a token. And I'm getting it. Then I would like to use it in another request. All is done in express.js. What is the best solution to provide it to the another request?

It looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const config = require('./config');

const app = express();

axios.post('URL1', {
  email: config.email,
  password: config.password,
})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data.token); //here I' getting the token
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });


const headers = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token ' + token } }; //here I would like to use (for the use of a second request)

axios.get('URL2', headers)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Of course I cannot just assign it to the variable. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it in another function just as shown below.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const config = require('./config');

const app = express();

  axios.post('URL1', {
    email: config.email,
    password: config.password,
  }).then((response) => {
    // calling function here
    return handleToken(response.data.token);
    console.log(response.data.token); //here I' getting the token
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

//second request will be handled here
const handleToken = (token) => {
  const headers = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token ' + token } }; 
//here I would like to use (for the use of a second request)

  axios.get('URL2', headers)
   .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
   });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

It's preferable if you write a separate function to avoid callback hell.

## EDIT - ROUTE WITH ASYNC/AWAIT

```
app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        let result = await axios.post('URL1', { email: config.email, password: config.password });
        let final = await handleToken(response.data.token);
        // other operations here
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        //handle error here
        console.error(err);
    }       
})      

//second request will be handled here
const handleToken = async (token) => {
    try {
        const headers = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token ' + token } };
        let response = await axios.get('URL2', headers);
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Atishay! I think your answer is just great, I tried to use callbacks but with a more then two chained requests it is becoming a mess. Your answer gives cleaner code. Just one more think: how now can I handle app.get route using response from a second external url call? I guess the problem is that it is async so I cannot just create another function in which I'd put app.get.

Comment: You can use async in routes like this

    `app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{`
     `//call some function`
     `await someFunction();`
    `})`

Comment: So it would be then: app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{ await handleToken(); }) ?

Comment: yes if you want to do the same thing with route. I'll update the code.

Comment: So if I'd like to send it the client side I just replace console.log(response) with res.send(response)?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!